# Unexpected token, expected "," while looping through objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to map through collection of objects inside an object and access the color item, but i get an error `Unexpected token, expected ","`. This is how i'm trying to map through. Is this the right way to map objects to retrieve value from colors.

```
  {Object.keys(this.state.lists).map((item, i) => 
    (this.state.lists[item].colors).map(item, i) =>
      <li  key={i}>{this.state.lists[item].colors[item]} </li>
  )}
```

`this.state.lists` looks like this:

```
 {{id: 1, colors:["red", "blue"]}, {id: 2, colors:["green", "yellow"]}}
```

Comment: `{{id: 1, colors:["red", "blue"]}, {id: 2, colors:["green", "yellow"]}}` is not a valid object in Javascript. Are you sure it's not supposed to be an array? If it is an array you can just do `{this.state.lists.map(item => ({item.colors.map(color => (<li  key={i}>{color}</li>)})}`

Comment: but i'm able to map through till here: `{Object.keys(this.state.lists).map((item, i) => 
    <li> {this.state.lists[item].colors} </li> )}

Comment: What does `typeof this.state.lists` give you?

Comment: type of gives me object. Sorry. my object is in this format: {1: {id: 1, colors:["red", "blue"]}, 2: {id: 2, colors:["green", "yellow"]}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) to your second `map` call, `.map(item, i)`. Hence the syntax error. It should instead be something like `.map((item, i) => ...)`.

Here's some cleaned up code that might make sense of this, though I haven't tested if it works with React:

```
const colors = Object.keys(this.state.lists).map(itemKey => {
    return <li key={itemKey}>{this.state.lists[itemKey].colors[0]}</li>
})
```

And when you render,

```
<ul>{colors}</ul>
```

Comment: I wanted to output the result like this: `{Object.keys(this.state.lists).map((item, i) => 
            <li key={i}>{this.state.lists[item].colors[0]}</li>
          )}`

Comment: Oh... you just want the first color. Ok see my updated answer

Comment: I was turning the returned items to objects. so I decided to just loop over the array instead . finally went with this: `{this.state.lists.map(detail =>  
  {this.state.lists.map((det, i)=> 
    <li>{detail.colors[i]}</li>
   )} `

Answer (score 1):

When using ES6 functions, you can omit the `()` of the parameters, only if you use 1 parameter. What you've done is actually closed your `map` before you even got to the fat arrow (`=>`). Your error is saying it doesn't understand the `,` in `map(item, i)`, since `map` doesn't accept a second parameter. Here's a bit of a break-down, followed by some optimized code for your problem.

A basic ES6 function is `() => {}`, where the parameters go between the `()` braces, and the code goes between the `{}`.

Here's a basic sum function: `(a, b) => { return a+b }`. Since this only has one line, and it's the return value, you can omit the `{}` brackets. i.e., `(a, b) => a+b`

Here's a hello function: `(name) => { return 'hello ' + name }`. Since it only has 1 parameter, you can use `name => { return 'hello ' + name }`. Or even using the above rule: `name => 'hello ' + name`.

These shortcuts can make code easier to write, but perhaps more difficult to understand. If in doubt, just always keep the `()` braces to avoid confusion.

```js
const obj = {
  1: {id: 1, colors:["red", "blue"]},
  2: {id: 2, colors:["green", "yellow"]}
}

for (key in obj) {
  const item = obj[key];
  item.colors.map((color, i) => {
    console.log( `<li key=${item.id}-${i}>${color}</li>`)
    // Below lines are commented out because StackOverflow
    // does not process JSX tags. Just uncomment and remove
    // the console.log above

    // return (
    //   <li key={item.id}-${i}>{color}</li>
    // )
  });
}
```

**NOTES:** Instead of using `Object.keys` to get an array of keys, I just use a `for...in` loop to accomplish the same thing.

## Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in